# Counting with a matcher

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, case-class

Is there a shorter way to write the following (`QuizWord` is a case class):

```
list.count { case w: QuizWord => true; case _ => false}
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider a similar pattern matching on the type using `collect` as follows,

```
list.collect { case w: QuizWord => w }.size
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes using `isInstanceOf` can be more readable than pattern matching. And this will be as efficient.

```
list.count(_.isInstanceOf[QuizWord])
```